# How i can prevent concurrency saving of data in Database in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

A problem i have faced during testing of my application which is

from two different browser i have open my application and open same page from i am doing some operation.
Then request for update data at same time from both browser. and data from both browser are save in database which is wrong.

I have done some code for prevent this issue like first check that values are exist in database or not. but this kind of validation can't prevent of concurrency saving of data.

Please help me. I need to resolve this issue.
Thanks in adavance

Comment: are you familiar with the "rowversion" concept? (historically and confusingly called "timestamp" in sql server)

Comment: Yeah but to implement "Timestamp" i have to add a column in every table which i am going to update. and at a time i am doing entries in 4-6 tables from web services. Should i have to implement "Timestamp" in my application? @MarcGravell

Comment: The only way to fully guard against a race condition in data access is to *either* use pessimistic locks (which would be a terrible idea here), or use optimistic concurrency; the simplest and most reliable form of optimistic concurrency is: a rowversion. Yes, there are other ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent concurrency error saving data by using Optimistic or Pessimistic locking

> Optimistic Locking

- There are 3 primary ways by which we can implement optimistic locking
  in .NET:-

  1. `Datasets`: - Dataset by default implement optimistic locking. They
     do a check of old values and new values before updating.
  2. `Timestamp Data type`: - Create a timestamp data type in your table
     and while updating check if old timestamp is equal to new timestamp.
  3. `Check old and new value`: - Fetch the values, do the changes and
     while doing the final updates check if the old value and current
     values in database are equal. If they are not equal then rollback or
     else commits the values

> Pessimistic Locking

- We can do pessimistic locking by specifying “IsolationLevel” in SQL
  Server stored procedures, ADO.NET level or by using transaction scope
  object.

For more information, check out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what i am doing is first i am assign values in dataset then send dataset to webservice for process. in Webservice all data are process and then perform Update, insert operation through procedure. then which one option will suit in my application? @Vizard

Comment: Use a `SqlDataAdapter` to call the `Update` function using `SQLDataAdapter` object's `Update` method by passing the dataset as its paramener, i.e. `sqldataadapterobject.Update(yourdataset)`. If there is some data chamge it will throw `DBConcurrencyException`...Checkout the link I provided above under the `Datasets` section for more information